# Replace HDFS form local disk to s3 getting error (org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService)

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs

We are trying to setup Cloudera 5.5 where HDFS will be working on s3 only for that we have already configured the necessory properties in Core-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
    <value>################</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
    <value>###############</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>s3a://bucket_Name</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>s3a://bucket_Name</value>
</property>
```

After setting it up we were able to browse the files for s3 bucket from command

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

And it shows the files available on s3 only.

But when we start the yarn services JobHistory server fails to start with below error and on launching pig jobs we are getting same error

```
PriviledgedActionException as:mapred (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No AbstractFileSystem for scheme: s3a
ERROR   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.jobhistory.JobHistoryUtils   
Unable to create default file context [s3a://kyvosps]
org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No AbstractFileSystem for scheme: s3a
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.createFileSystem(AbstractFileSystem.java:154)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.get(AbstractFileSystem.java:242)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$2.run(FileContext.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$2.run(FileContext.java:334)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
```

On serching on Internet we found that we need to set following properties as well in core-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>fs.s3a.impl</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
  <description>The implementation class of the S3A Filesystem</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
    <description>The FileSystem for  S3A Filesystem</description>
</property>
```

After setting the above properties we are getting following error

```
org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService   
Service org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager failed in state INITED; cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.<init>(java.net.URI, org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.<init>(java.net.URI, org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.newInstance(AbstractFileSystem.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.createFileSystem(AbstractFileSystem.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.get(AbstractFileSystem.java:242)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$2.run(FileContext.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$2.run(FileContext.java:334)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getAbstractFileSystem(FileContext.java:334)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:451)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:473)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.jobhistory.JobHistoryUtils.getDefaultFileContext(JobHistoryUtils.java:247)
```

The jars needed for this is in place but still getting the error any help will be great. Thanks in advance

**Update**

I tried to remove the property **fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl** but it give me the same first exception the one i was getting previously which is

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation 
PriviledgedActionException as:mapred (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No AbstractFileSystem for scheme: s3a
ERROR   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.jobhistory.JobHistoryUtils   
Unable to create default file context [s3a://bucket_name]
org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No AbstractFileSystem for scheme: s3a
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.createFileSystem(AbstractFileSystem.java:154)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.get(AbstractFileSystem.java:242)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$2.run(FileContext.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$2.run(FileContext.java:334)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getAbstractFileSystem(FileContext.java:334)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:451)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:473)
```

Comment: What is the location of the jar files? Are they in the same location on all the nodes?

Comment: @DurgaViswanathGadiraju The location is "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.0-1.cdh5.5.0.p0.8/lib/hadoop" and yes they are in same location on all nodes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not with the location of the jars.

The problem is with the setting:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
    <description>The FileSystem for  S3A Filesystem</description>
</property>
```

This setting is not needed. Because of this setting, it is searching for following constructor in `S3AFileSystem` class and there is no such constructor:

```
S3AFileSystem(URI theUri, Configuration conf);
```

Following exception clearly tells that it is unable to find a constructor for `S3AFileSystem` with `URI` and `Configuration` parameters.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.<init>(java.net.URI, org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)
```

To resolve this problem, remove `fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl` setting from `core-site.xml`. Just having `fs.s3a.impl` setting in `core-site.xml` should solve your problem.

**EDIT:**
`org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem` just implements `FileSystem`.

Hence, you cannot set value of `fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl` to `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem`, since `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem` does not implement `AbstractFileSystem`.

I am using Hadoop 2.7.0 and in this version `s3A` is not exposed as `AbstractFileSystem`.

There is JIRA ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11262 to implement the same and the fix is available in Hadoop 2.8.0.

Assuming, your jar has exposed `s3A` as `AbstractFileSystem`, you need to set the following for `fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl`:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3A</value>
</property>
```

That will solve your problem.

Comment: I tried that as well this gives me error "PriviledgedActionException as:mapred (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No AbstractFileSystem for scheme: s3a" Due to this only i've added the property in the core-stie.xml i will update my question also

Comment: Can you tell me, from where are you picking up the jar for s3a file system? Then, I can definitely solve your problem. I was looking at the implementation here: https://github.com/Aloisius/hadoop-s3a, which just implements FileSystem.

Comment: jar is in default location of the cloudera which is "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.0-1.cdh5.5.0.p0.8/lib/hadoop" the jar name is hadoop-aws-2.6.0-cdh5.5.0.jar

Comment: Thanks for your efforts and time we really appreciate it

Comment: I am using Hadoop 2.6.0 so we need to wait till 2.8.0. Thanks for your help and time

Comment: I tried that as well getting error "Service org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager failed in state INITED; cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3A not found"

Comment: So in conclusion we cannot replace s3 with localdisk for HDFS. Only we can use s3 for Input and output for MapReduce right?? Or is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Replace s3 with local disk? I am not clear about this statement. I see that, you are facing an exception when Job History server tries to write to s3. I have used s3 only for MapReduce jobs. Like I mentioned in the answer, I guess YARN support for s3 AbstractFileSystem implementation exists only from Hadoop 2.8.0.

Comment: what we are trying to achieve is to use s3 instead of local storage and for that only we've overridden the property fs.defaultFS and provided s3 details in place of namenodeip:8020.

Comment: OK. Got it. Let me dig deep into it. I see that, the exception is coming in JH Server: Service org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager failed in state INITED; cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.<init>(java.net.URI, org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration). I will go through this code and check if I can find something more.