# Spark History Server on S3A FileSystem: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

Spark can use Hadoop S3A file system `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem`. By adding the following into the `conf/spark-defaults.conf`, I can get spark-shell to log to the S3 bucket:

```
spark.jars.packages               net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:0.9.0,com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl          org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
spark.eventLog.enabled            true
spark.eventLog.dir                s3a://spark-logs-test/
spark.history.fs.logDirectory     s3a://spark-logs-test/
spark.history.provider            org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
```

Spark History Server also loads configuration from `conf/spark-defaults.conf`, but it seems not to load `spark.jars.packages` configuration, and throws `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer$.main(HistoryServer.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer.main(HistoryServer.scala)
```

The Spark source code for loading configuration is different in [SparkSubmitArguments.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmitArguments.scala#L82-L125)
and in [HistoryServerArguments.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/history/HistoryServerArguments.scala#L67), in particular the HistoryServerArguments does not seem to load packages.

Is there a way to add the `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem` dependency to the History Server?

Answer (score 8):

Did some more digging and figured it out. Here's what was wrong:

1. The JARs necessary for S3A can be added to `$SPARK_HOME/jars` (as described in [SPARK-15965](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15965))
2. The line

   ```
   spark.history.provider     org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
   ```

   in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf` will cause

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.<init>(org.apache.spark.SparkConf)
   ```

   exception. That line can be safely removed as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34319128/2651388).

**To summarize:**

I added the following JARs to `$SPARK_HOME/jars`:

- jets3t-0.9.3.jar (may be already present with your pre-built Spark binaries, seems to not matter which 0.9.x version)
- guava-14.0.1.jar (may be already present with your pre-built Spark binaries, seems to not matter which 14.0.x version)
- aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar (must be 1.7.4)
- hadoop-aws.jar (version 2.7.3) (probably should match the version of Hadoop in your Spark build)

and added this line to `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf`

```
spark.history.fs.logDirectory     s3a://spark-logs-test/
```

You'll need some other configuration to enable logging in the first place, but once the S3 bucket has the logs, this is the only configuration that is needed for the History Server.

Comment: We tried running this and the amount of events that get generated appear to be getting pushed into memory until job completion. This causes our larger jobs to fail. Do you know much about this? Small jobs worked fine and we had data in our history server ui.

Comment: I also needed to add: fs.s3a.fast.upload true

Answer (score 2):

on EMR emr-5.16.0:

I've added the following to my cluster bootstrap:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/aws-java-sdk-core-*.jar /usr/lib/spark/jars/
sudo cp /usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/aws-java-sdk-s3-*.jar /usr/lib/spark/jars/
sudo cp /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-aws.jar /usr/lib/spark/jars/
```

Then in the config of the cluster:

```
        {
          'Classification': 'spark-defaults',
          'Properties': {
            'spark.eventLog.dir': 's3a://some/path',
            'spark.history.fs.logDirectory': 's3a://some/path',
            'spark.eventLog.enabled': 'true'
          }
        }
```

If you're going to test this, first stop the spark history server:

```
sudo stop spark-history-server
```

Make the config changes

```
sudo vim /etc/spark/conf.dist/spark-defaults.conf
```

Then run the copying of JARs as above

Then restart the spark history server:

```
sudo /usr/lib/spark/sbin/start-history-server.sh
```

Thanks for the answers above!

Answer (score 1):

I added the following jars into my SPARK_HOME/jars directory and it works great:

- hadoop-aws-*.jar (Version must be same as hadoop-common which you have)
- aws-java-sdk-s3-*.jar (Choose the one compatible with hadoop-aws jar)
- aws-java-sdk-*.jar (Choose same version as above one)
- aws-java-sdk-core-*.jar (Choose same version as above one)
- aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-*.jar (Choose same version as above, Frankly not sure why this is needed but doesn't work for me without this jar).

Edit :

And my spark_defaults.conf has below 3 parameters set :

```
spark.eventLog.enabled : true
spark.eventLog.dir : s3a://bucket_name/folder_name
spark.history.fs.logDirectory : s3a://bucket_name/folder_name
```