# Invalid URI for NameNode address, s3a is not of schema 'hdfs'

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, ceph

I'm doing something about replacing HDFS with Ceph in hadoop environment (yarn), according to my research, the guideline from [hortonworks](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/87256/using-s3-as-defaultfs.html) and [Replace HDFS form local disk to s3 getting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314904/replace-hdfs-form-local-disk-to-s3-getting-error-org-apache-hadoop-service-abst) shows me that I need to modify `core-site.xml` under `$hadoop_home/etc/hadoop`.
My modification is like below:

```
<property>
        <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
        <value>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
        <value>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>s3a://bucket_name</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>s3a://bucket_name</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>fs.s3a.endpoint</name>
        <value>http://x.x.x.x:xxxx</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.imp</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3A</value>
</property>
```

However, when I tried to start the hadoop by `sbin/start-all.sh`, I got error like below,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI for NameNode address (check fs.defaultFS): s3a://bucket_name is not of scheme 'hdfs'.
```

For your information, my hadoop version is 3.2.0.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging into `hadoop` source code, I think this exception should be thrown.

The code below can't be skipped when you're trying to invoke `sbin/start-all.sh`.

```
  /**
   * @return address of file system
   */
  public static InetSocketAddress getNNAddress(URI filesystemURI) {
    String authority = filesystemURI.getAuthority();
    if (authority == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(
          "Invalid URI for NameNode address (check %s): %s has no authority.",
          FileSystem.FS_DEFAULT_NAME_KEY, filesystemURI.toString()));
    }
    if (!HdfsConstants.HDFS_URI_SCHEME.equalsIgnoreCase(
        filesystemURI.getScheme())) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(
          "Invalid URI for NameNode address (check %s): " +
          "%s is not of scheme '%s'.", FileSystem.FS_DEFAULT_NAME_KEY,
          filesystemURI.toString(), HdfsConstants.HDFS_URI_SCHEME));
    }
    return getNNAddress(authority);
  }
```

I don't need to start `namenode` and `secondarynamenode` since I use ceph as my backend storage system. The ceph itself can manage its so-called `datanode` by its `driver`.

Keep the thread here for anyone who might have same concern and welcome any comment about my understanding.