# UnsupportedFileSystemException when combine hadoop, spark and ceph

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, bigdata

**Update2**
Great thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34319128/3378204), it saved my day. 
For exception that's thrown in `Update1`, add below configuration:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3A</value>
  <description>The implementation class of the S3A AbstractFileSystem.</description>
</property>
```

As per the explanation in the answer, please also upgrade `hadoop` to at least `hadoop 2.8.0`.

Leave this thread here for others who run into the same situation.

**Update1**
According to similar issue listed at [Hortonworks](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/199043/unable-to-connect-hdfs-through-java-my-hadoop-vers.html), I realized I also need to specify the `fs.s3a.impl` explicitly, so I added below settings to `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml`,

```
<property>
  <name>fs.s3a.impl</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
  <description>The implementation class of the S3A Filesystem</description>
</property>
```

After that, the previous error disappears and new exception thrown,

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3A not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.createFileSystem(AbstractFileSystem.java:158)
```

Working it out.

According to my current understanding, the reason why `UnsupportedFileSystemException` is thrown is because `hadoop` doesn't "know" the existence of that file system. By specifying the implementation of specific filesystem through config file or runtime, the issue can be solved.

**Original**
I'm doing something about using `Spark-Sql` to query data under `Ceph`.

Currently, my software stack is `hadoop 2.7.3`, `spark 2.3.0` and `Ceph luminous`.

According to existed thread like [hadoop-2-9-2-spark-2-4-0-access-aws-s3a-bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53922709/hadoop-2-9-2-spark-2-4-0-access-aws-s3a-bucket/53924738#comment101128970_53924738), the version of `hadoop`, `aws related library` and `spark` are critical. I'm using `hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar` and `aws-java.sdk-1.7.4.jar` according to the solution mentioned. By putting those jars into `$SPARK_HOME/jars`, I solved [HIVE_STATS_JDBC_TIMEOUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57282164/any-update-about-hive-stats-jdbc-timeout-and-how-to-skip-it-in-source-level) issue, when I run `spark-sql` in shell, every thing works so far so good.

However, I'm stuck again when I tried to invoke `spark-sql` on top of `yarn`.
The command I used is `spark-sql --master=yarn`, and the exception thrown is

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl=null: No AbstractFileSystem configured for scheme: s3a
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.createFileSystem(AbstractFileSystem.java:160)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.get(AbstractFileSystem.java:249)
```

To solve that, I tried to put `hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar` and `aws-java.sdk-1.7.4.jar` into hadoop `classpath` like `$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib`.

However, things are still as old days.

Maybe I need to change the version of Spark? I had racked my brain. Any comment is welcomed, thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: If you solved your problem, why not write it up as an answer to this question?

Comment: @thsutton Good suggestion, but I think the update in the question is enough to help someone who might also come to this thread.